# Desktop strangeness > no mounted volumes [Ubuntu mate 18.04]

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate

Really puzzled by recent desktop behaviour.
Running Ubuntu Mate 18.04 LTS.

Was experiencing desktop slowdowns - was unable to copy paste or delete files or folders.
Also double clicking a folder sometimes would not open it and if it did the contents weren't visible, can only see spinning icon.
CPU process are normal, ie close to zero.

I rebooted and other strangeness happened.
None of my volumes are mounting on the desktop even though they are configured to using Mate tweak (attached)
Browsers and apps seem to launch ok.

Also if I go to Places in the menu all of my volumes open except for just one, WORK_1TB (attached link)

If I use Disks utility to check the filesystem on this external drive it suggests to repair but also warns that repairing may corrupt files. (attached link) This is my primary production volume. Before I attempt a repair I'd like to first back up important files but if I use GrSync I can see the volume but it won't open. Argh.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/f4Dum2r3pmasnFbWA

Can any linux wizards help me figure out what is happening?
Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: These sound like the symptoms of a hard disk running extremely slowly, it might be a hardware failure.

Comment: The NTFS is proprietary to Windows, although gparted might help, if you have the option to boot into windows and run chkdsk it could find additional issues to repair.

Comment: Thanks. Any risk of corrupting files with chkdsk?

Comment: You always have risk of corrupting data, even on SSD. And especially on HDD.

Comment: You should not try to run repair or diagnostic tools on that 1 GB NTFS volume WORK_1TB unless you run them from Windows.